# Notification header overlaps with top information bar

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, header

I've noticed that on the Parenting beta site, the notification bars slightly overlap the normal site header. This might be specific to Parenting but I think it might be a bug in the overall beta design.

This bug only appears at the third simultaneous notification. It looks correct for only one and two notification bars. I haven't seen four notifications so I can't tell how that would look.

[image]

I don't think that it's a browser quirk in itself, because it seems to work just fine for one and two notifications.

[image]

I'm using Firefox 9.0 on Windows XP, both US English.

**Update:**
At least on apple.SE there is no overlap even with three banners (I've upgraded to Ffox 10.0 in the meantime):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This bug is no longer relevant as notifications are now presented in a very different way.

Comment: Not on Area 51, but guess it's [meta-tag:status-too-minor]

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't know this "Area 51" that you speak of. I've never heard of it. It doesn't exist. And since it doesn't exist, I have no work to do there in that decrepit old code base. Case closed.